# reading unicode strings on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, unicode, types

an ancient code I maintain originally had this:

```
NSUInteger readUnicode(NSMutableString *string, signed char const * buf, signed long int offset, size_t bufsize)
{   
    NSUInteger initLength = [string length];
    signed char const * start = buf + offset;
    NSLog (@"--------> start: %S", start);

    [string appendFormat:@"%S", start];
    return [string length] - initLength;
}
```

with XCode throwing a warning "Format specifies type 'const unsigned short *' but the argument has type 'const signed char *' and suggesting to change appendFormat:@"%S" to appendFormat:@"%s"

when I did change %S to %s I started getting only ONE character in return string, regardless of the input.

So instead I changed the code to:

```
NSUInteger readUnicode(NSMutableString *string, signed char const * buf, signed long int offset, size_t bufsize)
{
    NSUInteger initLength = [string length];

    const unsigned short * start = (const unsigned short * )buf + offset;
    NSLog (@"--------> start: %S", start);

    [string appendFormat:@"%S", start];
    return [string length] - initLength;
}
```

... and now I seem to be getting all the characters and without the warning. 
Is this the way to deal with the warning ? Or perhaps I could/should have done something else ? (Other than changing the type of the input buf)

Thank you.

Comment: This probably should be tagged "objective-c" and not "c"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the way to deal with the warning ?

Perhaps not exactly. If you work with wide strings, why don't you declare your function to do so?

```
NSUInteger readUnicode(NSMutableString *string, unichar const *buf, signed long int offset, size_t bufsize)
                                                ^^^^^^^
                                       Note the use of "unichar"!
```

Then you don't need the ugly cast, you won't get the warning and your program wouldn't invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've tried replacing char with unichar, but that brings new fails. "conflicting types" and "expected )". perhaps there is more that needs to be changed in that definition to make that work

Comment: @farscape13 Perhaps there's more you need to understand about using long strings and character encodings...

Comment: no doubt, but learning new things all the time. thanks for your time,